# Group "getElementById" together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to merge multiple "ID" into a group

```
   $(function() {
    Ps.initialize(document.getElementById('block1'));
    });
    $(function() {
    Ps.initialize(document.getElementById('block2'));
    });
    $(function() {
    Ps.initialize(document.getElementById('block3'));
});
```

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but I suspect the answer is to use an array.

Comment: Or you could try to refactor the code & html to work with a class.

Comment: Or maybe you should give them a class, and use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: For a start, you don’t need to write `$(function() {`…`});` three times. Then you probably need to apply a `forEach` function on an array of the three IDs. That would at least decrease repetition. However, it’s still not clear what you mean by “group”.

Comment: I recommend you use a jquery selector rather than vanilla javascript

Comment: It would help to know what `ps` is and how the `init` method works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jquery with an attribute starts with selector (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) something like this

```js
 $(function() {
   var elements = $('[id^="block"]');
   $.each(elements, function(index, value){
     Ps.initialize(elements[index]);
    });         
});
```